# npm run start results in blank page only on Server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I have just installed a vue Landing page on my Mac. Terminal to folder and was running "npm install" and "npm run dev" it worked just fine.

But on the managed Server npm install works after sometimes only because it often gets killed with code 137. I created a subdomain for the project folder.

running npm run start gives me no errors but the url "subdomain.domain.legal" returns in blank page. The main  Is not getting replaced by anything. Port 8080 gives "Website not available"

Any ideas what specs or settings could be wrong on the managed Server?

## index.js

```
'use strict'
// Template version: 1.3.1
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.

const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  dev: {

    // Paths
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},

    // Various Dev Server settings
    host: 'subdomain.domain.legal', // can be overwritten by process.env.HOST
    port: 8080, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in use, a free one will be determined
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    errorOverlay: true,
    notifyOnErrors: true,
    poll: false, // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-watchoptions-

    // Use Eslint Loader?
    // If true, your code will be linted during bundling and
    // linting errors and warnings will be shown in the console.
    useEslint: true,
    // If true, eslint errors and warnings will also be shown in the error overlay
    // in the browser.
    showEslintErrorsInOverlay: false,

    /**
     * Source Maps
     */

    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#development
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    // If you have problems debugging vue-files in devtools,
    // set this to false - it *may* help
    // https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/options.html#cachebusting
    cacheBusting: true,

    cssSourceMap: true
  },
```

## error after npm run start (sometimes)

```
 I  Your application is running here: http://subdomain.domain.legal:8080                                        Killed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137
npm ERR! tovo_vue@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 137
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tovo_vue@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-05-31T11_47_21_305Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 137
npm ERR! tovo_vue@1.0.0 start: `npm run dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 137
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tovo_vue@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-05-31T11_47_21_313Z-debug.log
```

## HTML code of (blank) page

```
<html><head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="pixelstrap">
    <meta name="description" content="xy">
    <meta name="keywords" content="xy">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Fav icon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" hre="/static/favicon.png">
    <!-- Font Family-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body id="nav-scroller" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="0">

  <div id="app"></div>


</body></html>
```

## free -g:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             31           7          10           0          12          22
Swap:             3           0           3
```

## ps aux | grep node

```
user 1422  0.0  0.0  16712   968 pts/1    S+   14:18   0:00 grep node
```

Comment: We're going to need to see more than just that. Code 137 implies that the process was given a `SIGKILL` from the outside.

Comment: yea I´m new to coding actually so just tell me everything and I´ll add as quickly as I can!

Comment: Upload `/usr/home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-05-31T11_47_21_313Z-debug.log` somewhere. Typically this issue is related to `oomkiller`, but with 10GB of free RAM there's something else at play here.

Answer (score -1):

Once kill everything and start again below the code.

```
 ps aux | grep node
 sudo kill -9
```

Also,

```
sudo lsof -i:<PORT_NO>
```

close the instance for present time but unable to stop the process in background. So for one time,

```
sudo kill <PID>
```

works, but again when we update our code and save, this problem occurs again as with Nodemon.

So exit the terminal will solve the problem. OR

```
killall -9 node
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! unfortunatly on our managed Server I do not have access to sudoers file.. I have added the output of ps aux | grep node to my post!

Comment: Your solution to an out-of-memory-related `SIGKILL` is to kill all node processes indiscriminately of what they are or what they are running? Sounds like asking for trouble if it isn't a dev machine. Consider the implications of your suggestions to people.